# Ubuntu 19.10 login loop after software updates

Tags: 19.10

here's what happened:

I installed Ubuntu 19.10 without any problems **but with automatic login enabled**.

**Then**, I installed the **software updates** and rebooted my PC. After that, the system was asking me to type my password (he didn't to that before) and then I couldn't log into my account anymore, even though my password was right. (the famous **login loop** problem)

Finally I did found a solution (and was because the automatic login). I changed the file **"/etc/gdm/custom.conf"** (via Ctrl + Alt + F3 (Virtual Terminal)) and commented these lines:

```
AutomaticLoginEnable=True
AutomaticLogin=yourusername
```

After that, I rebooted my PC and everything worked fine.

Anyway, I just wanted to share it with you guys in case you didn't see this solution yet.

I don't know if it is a bug or something. (I guess it is)

I hope this helps someone out there.

Good luck and have a nice day.